# How to Change Magento 2 default theme to RTL

Tags: magento-2.1, css, html

Pls Help.!, How to Change  Magento 2 default theme (Blank) to RTL layout for Arabic.?

Answer (score 3):

Add sub theme of default http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

and just put

```
html { direction:rtl; }
```